# Bottom ion-tabs overlapping on last portion of ion-content on iOS devices

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios11, ionic5

On iOS devices, last content inside ion-content getting overlapped by ion-tabs located at the bottom. Even the user tries to scroll to bottom content still hides behind the bottom tabs. This reproducibility of this behavior is sometimes, especially the user tries to navigate to another page and come back.

[image: issue screenhot]

```
<ion-content no-bounce has-bouncing="false" forceOverscroll="false"  fullscreen="true"   >
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let option of options">
    <ion-col>
        ...
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button>
      <ion-icon [name]="icon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    ...
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

This is working correctly on android devices however the issue is with iOS devices especially iPhones (iOS 11).

So far I have tried adding `no-bounce has-bouncing="false" forceOverscroll="false"` attributes to `ion-content` but still no luck.

**Ionic info:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.3.0 (C:\Users\tanmay.m\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.6
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.0.1
   @capacitor/core : 2.0.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.13.1) : 0.10.0
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```